# How do I use Yeoman's git.name(); mixin?

Tags: gulp, yeoman

I'm running yeoman with gulp and I want to print a user's github name using this mixin: http://yeoman.io/generator/actions_user.html#.git.name

Simply adding `var username = git.name();` doesn't work

How can I use this mixin and other mixins in yeoman? Do I need to require or include anything in index.js file other than yeoman itself?

Answer (score 3):

No need to import anything. Just prefix the call with `this.user`. This applies to your example as such:

```
var username = this.user.git.name());
```

This makes it somewhat inconsistent with the other mixins outside of `this.user`, which can be accessed directly via `this`, eg. `this.installDependencies()`.